# ContactsContract.Groups.SUMMARY_WITH_PHONES cause crash

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have some code which queries the contacts database as follows:-

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_SUMMARY_URI;
String[] projection = new String[] {
    ContactsContract.Groups._ID,
    ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE,
    ContactsContract.Groups.SUMMARY_WITH_PHONES,
};
String selection = ContactsContract.Groups.SUMMARY_WITH_PHONES + ">0";
if (Version.androidVersion() <= 15) selection += " AND " + ContactsContract.Groups.GROUP_VISIBLE + "=1";
String[] selectionArgs = null;
String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
return new CursorLoader(r.activity, uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
```

It has worked just fine for quite some time, on quite a number of devices. I was testing it today on a new Huawei P8 (Android 7.0) and it failed with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column summ_phones
```

Now, `summ_phones` is the string associated with `ContactsContract.Groups.SUMMARY_WITH_PHONES`[(Android source code)](http://androidxref.com/7.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/provider/ContactsContract.java#7621). And, indeed, if I take out reference to that then the code stops crashing. I can find no reference to this option being deprecated though.

What have I missed? How can the query be made to work?